# pandas - parsing MySql results

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I am using python pandas to execute query on MySql. In UI side using Flot API to represent the MySql data. Below is the existing implementation,

```
query2 = f"""select time, value from NWSTAT 
             where time > \'{from_date}\' 
             and time < \'{to_date}\'"""
result2 = pd.read_sql(query2, engine)
return result2.to_json(orient='records')
```

Getting result in below format

```
[{"time": 1581931200000, "value": 0.0}, {"time": 1581931200000, "value": 0.0}, 
 {"time": 1581931200000, "value": 0.0}, {"time": 1581931200000, "value": 0.0}]
```

From this response I am creating belwo structure for Flot API in UI Javascript side,

```
[[1581931200000,0],[1581931200000,0],[1581931200000,0],[1581931200000,0]]
```

Is there any way to do this in python side itself with out any iterations? Directly from query result.

Using Flask server.
UI side: JQuery, Handlebar JS

EDIT: **In accepted answer second approach takes lesser time**.. Below is the time taken for both approach for 240k records

```
 First one: --- 1.6689300537109375e-06 seconds ---
 Second one: --- 0.5330650806427002 seconds ---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is if convert both columns to numpy array format of integers is changed to floats.

```
print (json.dumps(result2.to_numpy().tolist()))
```

First idea is create lists from `.values()` of dictionaries and convert to `json`:

```
import json

query2 = f"""select time, value from NWSTAT 
             where time > \'{from_date}\' 
             and time < \'{to_date}\'"""
result2 = pd.read_sql(query2, engine)
return json.dumps([list(x.values()) for x in result2.to_dict(orient='records')])
```

Or change fomrat by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `l` for lists and then use `zip` with mapping lists, last convert to `json`:

```
import json

query2 = f"""select time, value from NWSTAT 
             where time > \'{from_date}\' 
             and time < \'{to_date}\'"""
result2 = pd.read_sql(query2, engine)
return json.dumps(list(map(list, zip(*result2.to_dict(orient='l').values()))))
```

Comment: thanks for the updated solution, second one gives the same result in lesser time. Is there any option to handle **NaN** value?

Comment: @saravanakumar - Whats happen if NaNs? removed rows?

Comment: I handled it in mysql side!!!! select time, **COALESCE(value,0)** from NWSTAT .... This solves my problem... Thank you so much for you timely help!!!

Comment: Check the response time for 240K records 
==first method
--- 1.6689300537109375e-06 seconds ---
==Second method
--- 0.5330650806427002 seconds ---